# Application Links item in Open/SaveFileDialog in C#

Tags: c#, windows, api, windows-7, openfiledialog

When showing the open file dialog, I want to show up the "App,lication Links" category in the left side pane on Vista/7. Visual Studio does that too when opening project files.

### [image: Additional Links]

How can I do this with a standard OpenFileDialog-Object in C#? I am using WPF by the way, but I don't think that matters in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`FileDialog.CustomPlaces`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.customplaces.aspx). That MSDN link contains some sample code to get you going. Ultimately this is wrapping the native functionality exposed by [IFileDialog::AddPlace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775946.aspx).